# Sony Smart Extension API Device Support?

Tags: android, api, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have read the docs at Sony and for their Smart Extensión API, it doesn't mentions the SWR10(Smartband)

Have anyone tried to use the API with this device or knows if there's no actual support for developing to this device?

Thanks in advance.
PS. Sorry for my english, it isn't my main language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SmartBand SWR10 is not supported by the Smart Extension API.  Currently, there is no official SDK for developing apps for the SWR10.

Comment: So there's no way to develop applications that work with the SWR10 then?